# Debugging Mergesort Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

Okay, I know this question doesn't show research effort, but I've been going through this code so many times and I couldn't figure out was I was doing wrong. I know there are many Mergesort implementation examples but I wanted to do it my way. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MergeSort
{
    public static int[] mergeSort(int[] arr)
    {
        if (arr.length > 1)
        {
            int[] arr1 = splitLeft(arr);
            int[] arr2 = splitRight(arr);
            arr1 = mergeSort(arr1);
            arr2 = mergeSort(arr2);
            return merge(arr1, arr2);
        }
        else
            return arr;
    }

    public static int[] splitLeft(int[] arr)
    {
        int middle = arr.length / 2;
        int[] newarr = new int[middle];
        for (int i = 0; i < middle; i++)
            newarr[i] = arr[i];
        return newarr;
    }

    public static int[] splitRight(int[] arr)
    {
        int middle = arr.length / 2;
        int[] newarr = new int[arr.length - middle];
        for (int i = 0; i + middle < arr.length; i++)
            newarr[i] = arr[i + middle];
        return newarr;
    }

    public static int[] merge(int[] arr1, int[] arr2)
    {       
        int[] sorted = new int[arr1.length+arr2.length];

        int i1 = 0;
        int i2 = 0;
        int i = 0;

        while (i1 < arr1.length && i2 < arr2.length)
        {
            if (arr1[i1] < arr2[i2])
            {
                sorted[i] = arr1[i1];
                i1++;
            }

            else
            {
                sorted[i] = arr2[i2];
                i2++;
            }
        i++;
        }

        while (i1 < arr1.length) 
        {
            sorted[i] = arr1[i1];
            i1++;
            i++;
        }

        while (i2 < arr2.length) 
        {
            sorted[i] = arr1[i2];
            i2++;
            i++;
        }
        return sorted;
    }

    public static int getNum(int x)
    {
        int num = (int)(Math.random()*x + 1);
        return num;
    }

    public static void printArr(int[] arr)
    {
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }

    static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String [ ] args)
    {
        int i;

        System.out.println("Type the length of the array");
        int n = reader.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Type the range of the random numbers generator");
        int range = reader.nextInt();

        int[]arr = new int[n];

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            arr[i] = getNum(range);

        printArr(arr);

        int[] sorted = new int[n];
        sorted = mergeSort(arr);

        printArr(sorted);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your `merge` function?

Comment: Is there any problem with the split functions?

Comment: you should have done it very simply, By the by what you are trying to do in left split and right split. Try to reason yourself why you have written that code is it necessary and all. You can find the mistakes what and all you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `splitRight` function.  Consider this code:

```
for (int i = middle; i < arr.length; i++)
    newarr[i] = arr[i];
```

This tries to copy the `i`th element from `arr` to the `i`th position of `newarr`, but this is incorrect.  For example, if the array `arr` has ten elements, you want to copy element 5 of `arr` to position 0 of `newArr`, element 6 of `arr` to position 1 of `newarr`, etc.

To fix this, consider trying something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i + middle < arr.length; i++)
    newarr[i] = arr[i + middle];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work when trying to split an array with a length which is not even, but I thought the arr.length-middle should take care of that. Do you have any idea what might cause this?

Comment: Without seeing more code I'm not sure I can help.  You should post the complete code, including `merge`, as a separate question with the above bug fix.

Comment: I added the whole code. I compared my `merge` function with other examples on the internet and it should work as intended, however I get ArrayIndexOutOfBounds so it is possible that something is wrong with the `merge` function.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
for (int i = middle; i < arr.length; i++)
            newarr[i] = arr[i];
```

You are surely asking for positions in the original array and at the same time looking for them in the new array (which happens to be shorter).